# filterValue change listiner jQuery Typeahead Search

Tags: jquery, typeahead

I've used [jquery typeahead](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/) in my project. I want to get the value of a filterValue when the value is changed.

[image]

for example, when click on county, get selected value(i.e country):

```
$('div.typeahead-container').on('change', 'span.typeahead-filter-value', function(event){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Edit: thank you for replay. this is [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/98g0ztLq/1/), but do not run it beautifully

Comment: can you please create a demo on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
$('div.typeahead-container').on('click', '.input-group-btn li', function (event) {
    alert('okay');
});
```

runningcoder is using a bootstrap layout for the dropdown and by default bootstrap does not provide an events for dropdown item click.

Here is the [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/98g0ztLq/2/)

Hope this helps.